# Ionic 3 serve like Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap

I want to develop Ionic 3 hybrid mobile application, but i am confused about one part, is there functionality similar to Phonegap functionality, Phonegap have possibility to serve application over his IP address, so , if i have installed Phonegap app on mobile, i can enter IP adress and port on what address is served Phonegap app and i can see how application looks like and how application works.
Does Ionic 3 have this functionality? I can see that in Ionic i can see in browser over localhost:port, but i need to see on physical device, to enter IP address and port to see how application works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have two ways to do it:
**1. Using `ionic serve`**:
First your run `ionic serve` in your command line. Then when the local server start you will see the address for external server in command port (You need to search in command port to see it). It looks like:

```
[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.*.*:8100, http://192.168.*.*:8100
```

Just enter the external address in your mobile browser and your app will run in it with livereload feature.
*Pros:* Fast livereload 
*Cons:* Can not use native function. Some UI may differnt from your actual app
**2. Using `ionic cordova run android -l`** 
Connect your device with your computer then run the command above. Make sure they ar using **same wifi**. That is all you need.
*Pros:* Can use native function. It is actual your app when you build in device 
*Cons*: Slow livereload
**3. Using Ionic Dev App**
Download Ionic [Dev App](http://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/) and follow instruction in the link.
*Pros:* Can use native function. It is actual your app when you build in device. Fast livereload. Others can see your app if in same network
*Cons*: Did not found  :-)

Comment: @duanx thank you on answer, also, i would only add there is one more possible option, that is View App, as i can see, there is to options, with public and private View app, for private it need to pay.

Comment: @MPetrovic:Now you have another option is Ionic Dev App. See my updated answer